# ASP.MVC ValidationSummary on success

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

ValidationSummary can easly display error messages.

But how can I make it a success message I return from my action.

I am calling this action within Ajax request.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

As you've discovered ValidationSummary is for displaying error messages. If you are using AJAX you could have your action return messages in JSON:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
     // Do something
     return Json(new { message = "success" });
}
```

And then call it:

```
$.post('/home/foo', { }, function(json) {
    alert(json.message);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, I want to do something like this

*`ModelState.AddModelError("SUCCESS",  mySuccessMessage);`*

I'm thinking about modifing the CSS of ValidationSummary to display the message in green color.

but I don't know where this CSS is located